# Как взять данные из сообщения в дискорде?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

пишу бота для дискорда. Столкнулся с проблемой: нужно взять данные из введённого сообщения. Например:

Человек пишет: **!хч 05.09-20:00**. Как боту взять **05.09-20:00** и добавить в ответе
*hch = discord.Embed(title='Хрустальный чертог в **сюда это самое время**'*. Буду очень благодарен!

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)

async def хч(ctx):

    who = ctx.message.author
    hch = discord.Embed(title='Хрустальный чертог в ' ,
                        description=f'{who.mention} Собирает людей в рейд!\n \nЗаписываемся ниже')
    hch.set_image(url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/481766947495739393/883987328945758208/111.jpg')
    hch.set_thumbnail(url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/481766947495739393/883988530655797248/1630829680564.png')
    await ctx.send_message(ctx.channel, embed=hch)
```

Comment: в коде есть ошибка в последней строчке, должно быть `await ctx.send(embed=hch)`

Comment: Не используйте pass_context, такого аргумента у декоратора команд уже давно не существует, впрочем как и send_message.

Comment: Если вы довольны ответом на вопрос, то, пожалуйста, оцените его.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте аргументы команд:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#parameters

```
@client.command()
async def хч(ctx, time_range: str):
    hch = discord.Embed(title=f"Хрустальный чертог в {time_range}",
                        description=f'{ctx.message.author} Собирает людей в рейд!\n\nЗаписываемся ниже')
    hch.set_image(url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/481766947495739393/883987328945758208/111.jpg')
    hch.set_thumbnail(url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/481766947495739393/883988530655797248/1630829680564.png')
    await ctx.send(embed=hch)
```

И поищите туториал/мануал поновее, половины методов в вашем коде, [не существует в текущей версии библиотеки](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html).

Comment: Я в комментариях написал, что ошибка была. Уже давно исправил на новое всё. Спасибо за ответ, я попробую!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так(*в отдельной переменной записать*):

```
async def хч(ctx, message):
    time_title = f'Хрустальный чертог в {message.text}'
    hch = discord.Embed(title=time_title,
                        description=f'{who.mention} Собирает людей в рейд!\n \nЗаписываемся ниже')
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'text' ошибка

Comment: @Oyster исправил, посмотрите

Comment: Первый аргумент - всегда контекст в командах: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#invocation-context

Comment: @Fixator10 Верно, спасибо за замечание, не обратил внимание..